# How can I wrap tables into a more generic class for use with multiple data contexts?

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, mapping, datacontext

I have two different DataContexts (SQL Databases) that have the same data, just with slightly different naming:

DB1: Serialnumber Productnumber
DB2: SerialNumber ProductNumber Result

So I want to be able to wrap these tables in a class that will let me get back the serial number and product number regardless of the DataContext that it is coming from. I've looked into DataTableMappings, but I really have no idea where to begin. I'd also like this to work via LINQ and direct SQL queries. Again, I'd like it to be as generic as possible so I can use the same LINQ queries for the two different contexts. What is it that I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, you'd probably want to consider coding against interfaces with your business logic - that way you can pass in DB1 or DB2 objects as long as their classes implement the interfaces specified.

Comment: This is what I'm asking how to do. I've tried a few ways, but none seem to give me all the results I want (mostly incompatibilities with LINQ).

Comment: Yes, i've been there (L2S is a pain to get to work with interfaces when property names differ from field names in the DB), but there are ways to make it work.  Have a look at this, perhaps it might give you a few ideas - 

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526402/linq2sql-doesnt-like-it-when-you-wrap-column-properties-with-properties-in-an-interface


http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/5691e0ad-ad67-47ea-ae2c-9432e4e4bd46

Comment: Those links helped a lot, specifically the first one. Looks like it might be a little more trouble than it's worth, but it does look manageable. We have decided to take a different route on our project, but this is very valuable information. Thanks!

Comment: No probs.  It might look like a bit of trouble, but i've using that approach for the last 2 years and it's (mostly) a pleasure to work with.  Being able to use the same code on multiple tables with virtually the same structure with little effort gives me that warm, tingly feeling inside :)